# .NET 2.0/VS2005 - BringToFront() simply does not work

Tags: .net, winforms

BringToFront doesn't work. after called, my form still stays under an file explorer window or any other window it's under. It's clearly visible. It's otherwise fine, but it simply does not move to the foreground when this is called. not even if i do a "show" before, or after.

I can't have the form "topMost" all the time. I just want it to pop into the foreground as if someone clicked its caption. if other windows are shown after it, it should be under them.

I am so desperate with this C**p not working I'm considering doing a mouse click simulation that'll shoot my window/form to the front.

Is this really a bug in .NET?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you want the [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) method instead.  "BringToFront" is inherited from the base "Control" class and just reorders a control within the current form.

Comment: RM1970, I went through the same painful experience of not being able to make it work with BringToFront until I found this post. Thank you for a great question.